# IIS Express Ports - Multiple Ports in File

Tags: iis-express, azure-ad-graph-api

Dumb question, but I cannot find it.  Why does IIS express use 2 ports (Sample file below).

Secondly, in this exercise here, when I'm requested to setup an app, it references 3007, which I cannot access.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/identity-application-types/5-exercise-web-apps-call-apis

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:3007",
      "sslPort": 3007
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IdentityWeb": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`iisSettings` is used when running VS2019 or other visual studio version IDE.**

**`IdentityWeb`(peojectname) is for dotnet command line use.**

*Offical doc:* [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development-and-launchsettingsjson)

**These are just different configurations of the project according to the operating environment, no need to entangle.**

## Test steps.

---

1. Delete `iisSettings` in vs2019, then change properties, then check `launchSettings.json` file.

   Before deleted the ssl port is 44316, then we delete it. After changed properties, it generated new ssl port.

   [image]

   Now, we can run project(we **need to restart IDE** [vs2019]), it works fine.

   [image]

---

2. Modify applicationUrl in IdentityWeb.

   [image]

   Open cmd or powershell in project folder.

   [image]

   [image]

---